# Why does this TinyMCE AJAX integration work 9/10 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I've got a TinyMCE implementation that works somewhere around 80-90% of the time, but for that last percent, the content of the editor fails to populate - for lack of better phrasing.

Effectively, upon page load, a jQuery AJAX call reaches out to a PHP page that grabs some content from my database. Upon retrieval, I set the value of the TinyMCE instance to the content of the response. I've gone a few rounds with this, first with a custom AJAX build, and recently a jQuery build. In both cases I get about the same results - that the editor loads, the content comes back from the server, and every once in a while, the text area ends up blank.

The latest attempt at this is much shorter than the earlier ones, but either way, I still end up with effectively the same result. I've also tried repainting the TinyMCE instance after the content is loaded to no avail.

The result of the two console logs are identical - and the expected response from my server - even in the case of a failure. So the value IS getting set, but the content is not visible.

```
function LoadAgenda()
{
    $.ajax(
    {       
        url: 'http://www.example.com/agenda.php?AgencyID=' + AgencyID + '&date=' + AgendaDate,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(Response)
    {
        console.log(Response);

        $('#AgendaContent').val(Response);

        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");

        console.log($('#AgendaContent').val());
    });
}
```

And finally, for the record, I'm using TinyMCE 4.1.6.

If anyone needs more information than this, I'm happy to oblige.

Comment: try doing it the opposite way by using the `setData()` method of tinyMce. I'm not as familiar with tinyMce API as I am with other editors so function name may not be correct and you likely need to target the specific instance as well

Answer (score 0):

What happens first? The editor getting loaded or the ajax call completing? If your ajax call is happening after the editor is loaded, I don't think .val() is going to work, since it's no longer a simple textarea after TinyMCE initializes it. Try this:

- Make the ajax call only [after the editor is initialized](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onInit)
- Change .val() to [setContent()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

Comment: Well, as much as I appreciate the input - the .val call Does work 90% of the time, as does setting it through the DOM .value property. I'll be trying to set via the editors setContent method today, and I'll report back. For the record, I'm making the AJAX call on a jQuery .ready callback, which as far as I can tell, gets called after the tinyMCE.init 100% of the time. I have to figure out why my tinyMCE.activeEditor variable isn't getting set before I can setContent properly, but hopefully that will be easy enough.

Comment: Well, finding my tinyMCE instance was easy enough once I figured out that I'm a dunce. Check. After figuring that out, I put in a tinyMCE.get() == null check, and in the case that it is null, I set a timeout back to my AJAX method. Resolved. Thanks for your help.